# DecisionTreeDiscretiser un-normalize

Tags: python, pandas, feature-extraction

I'm using `DecisionTreeDiscretiser` to normalize columns of continuous values. The dataset I'm using is too large to include here, but it contains a set of positive integers. e.g. 1, 5, 80, 560, labels are either 1 or 0. After discretizing the values, I noticed that the replaced discrete values after transform are decimals:

```py
data = df[['foo', 'class']].dropna()
disc = DecisionTreeDiscretiser(cv=3)
disc.fit(data, data['class'])
train_t = disc.transform(data)
print(train_t['foo'].unique())
```

For `{"foo": [1,1,1,3,3,3,3], "class": [0,0,1,1,0,1,1]}`, this prints something like `[0.33333333 0.75]`.

I'm assuming this is because the `DecisionTreeDiscretiser` normalized the values? How can I easily get the original back? i.e. something like `[-inf,2][2,inf]`?